# Email form from a website via PHP issues

Tags: php, html, forms, email, web

I am coding a personal website and having an issue with my contact from. If you can help me find what's wrong I would really appreciate it.

The link to the website is www.tiryakicreative.com and the code for the php form is given below:

```
<div id="form">
<form id="ajax-contact-form" action="contact_form/send_form_email.php…
<fieldset class="info_fieldset">
<div id="note"></div>
<div id="fields">
<label>Name</label>
<input class="textbox" type="text" name="name" value="" />
<label>E-Mail</label><input class="textbox" type="text" name="email" value="" />     
<label>Subject</label>
<input class="textbox" type="text" name="subject" value="" />
<label>Message</label>
<textarea class="textbox2" name="message" rows="5" cols="25"></textarea>
<label> </label><input class="button" type="image" src="send2.gif" id="submit"   Value="Send Message" />    
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the php code for the given html code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
$email_to = "ian_tiryaki@hotmail.com";
$email_subject = "New Email from Website";


function died($error) {
// ERROR CODE GOES HERE
echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
echo "These errors appear below.";
echo $error."";
echo "Please go back and fix these errors.";
die();
}

// validation expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['name']) || 
!isset($_POST['email']) ||
!isset($_POST['subject']) ||
!isset($_POST['message'])) {
died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.'); 
}

$first_name = $_POST['name']; // required
$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
$telephone = $_POST['subject']; // not required
$comments = $_POST['message']; // required

$error_message = "";
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z…
if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.';
}
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
$error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.';
}
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
$error_message .= 'The subject you entered does not appear to be valid.';
}
if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
$error_message .= 'The message you entered do not appear to be valid.';
}
if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
died($error_message);
}
$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
$bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:",…
return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
$email_message .= "Subject: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
$email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 
?>

<!-- include success html here -->

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: What happens when you try to send an email?

Comment: blank page opens and no action...

Comment: When PHP gives you a blank page, you should check the web server log files. Also, I assume the ellipses ("…") are not present in the actual code.

Comment: I double checked the code for ellipses and no, they are not present.

Comment: It's kind of strange syntax to have a function in the middle of that code segment. You should def check the server log for error messages.

Comment: It does look like something is causing an error. If you are unable to check the server error logs then try echoing something out to the screen at various points in your script to narrow down where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Are you receiving the emails after the user sends the email?

Comment: That is a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

to the top of your script.

You could also try removing the @ from the mail command

```
mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
```

As this will be suppressing any errors that is being generated.

It could be something as simple as the PHP mail function having additional headers disabled (some hosts do this for security reasons) in which case the mail function will fail.

Answer (score 0):

set this is in your action form ...
and you will definately get mail from here..
and although there is an error you may be use use below code for send mail using php without declare a variable...
like

```
$email_to=$_POST['email'];
$email_subject=$_POST['subject'];
$email_message=$_POST['message'];
$headers=$_POST['title'];

    mail('$email_to', '$email_subject', '$email_message', '$headers');
```

otherwise 
use below code for send mail

```
mail('$_POST['email']','$_POST['subject']','$_POST['message']','$_POST['title']');
```

Comment: Simply using the POST array directly is both a security risk and is no guarantee you will "definitely get a mail from here" as there may be other reasons the mail function is failing.